# What is causing this issue? (Moving mesh vertices creates extra faces)

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, vertices

So, I've been having this issue. It has happened twice so far. I created a circle and then filled it. I tried moving some vertices, but kept seeing some faces moving along.

Then I created a curved and then filled it up. The same thing is happening. Only the vertices I'm moving should move. How can I fix this?

This is a flat mesh. I don't see why it's creating some faces on its sides when moving it.

Front view
[image]

Side view
[image]

Another angle
[image]

Comment: If you move the vertices on  a large ngon like that, you are creating non planar and overlapping geometry. Avoid faces that have more than 4 vertices. Don't fill a circle. use Grid fill so that you have more subdivisions. Watch a few more videos on how to model. It will save you a lot of time down the line.

Comment: Forgot to mentioned that I'm a beginner. Also, sorry I'm not sure what you mean with the first sentence.

I'm trying to move the top middle art of this mesh forward to make it kind of curve at the middle. I want to make a leaf.

Comment: non-planar means the face (n-gon) ist not in a plane. Thats what is clearly visible in your second and third image. Also @susu make an answer out of it. Maybe also link to the Blender Manual for non-planar, self-intersection and n-gon.